# Got different prices from SqrtPriceX96 and from Tick on Uniswap

Tags: ethers.js, javascript, uniswapv3, price

I trying to get price (ratio) from pool on Uniswap v3 by JS with ethers.js.

But I got a slightly different prices from SqrtPriceX96 and from Tick, for some reason.

**SqrtPriceX96 and Tick took from 'slot0' of the pool ETH/USDT (fee 500)**

```
 const slot0 = await pool.slot0.call()
 const priceFromSqrtPriceX96 = sqrtToPrice(slot0[0].toString(), tokenDecimals0, tokenDecimals1);
 const priceFromTick = tickToPrice(slot0[1], tokenDecimals0, tokenDecimals1);
 console.log('priceFromSqrtPriceX96',priceFromSqrtPriceX96);
 console.log('priceFromTick',priceFromTick);
```

**priceFromSqrtPriceX96 to price function:**

```
const sqrtToPrice = (sqrt, tokenDecimals0, tokenDecimals1) => {
    const numerator = sqrt ** 2
    const denominator = 2 ** 192
    let ratio = numerator / denominator
    const decimalShift = 10 ** (Number(tokenDecimals0) - Number(tokenDecimals1));
    return ratio * decimalShift;
}
```

**Tick to price function:**

```
const tickToPrice = (tick, tokenDecimals0, tokenDecimals1) => {
    const ratio = (1.0001 ** Number(tick));
    const decimalShift = 10 ** (Number(tokenDecimals0) - Number(tokenDecimals1));
    return ratio * decimalShift;
}
```

**Result:**

```
priceFromSqrtPriceX96 1915.6314519322657
priceFromTick 1915.4823772526233
```

Can Some one help me please?
Why they are different?
Or maybe i do something wrong?

Comment: It seems it's probably more about the timestamp when they were fetched.

Comment: They were fetched from slot0 with one call, so they from same timestapm